# Angular ui-grid custom filter not working on multiple grids

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I have two grids on the same page and the data is flowing into two separate tabs. This functionality works fine with no issue.

My problem is that the custom sorting and filtering seems to be bubbling and I can only get the filtering and sorting to work on one grid and not the other.

Below are my two sortListener functions

```
    var sortListener = function( grid, sortColumns ) {
      console.log('sort');
      var page = $scope.gridApi.pagination.getPage();
      var pageSize = $scope.gridOptions1.paginationPageSize;
      var url = getGridPageUrl(page, pageSize);
      var columns = $scope.gridApi.grid.columns;
      var payload = getGridPagePayload(sortColumns, columns);
      sendGridPageRequest(url, payload);
    };

    var sortSiteListener = function(grid, sortColumns) {
      console.log('sortOnSiteListener');
      var page      = $scope.gridApi.pagination.getPage();
      var pageSize  = $scope.gridOptions12.paginationPageSize;
      var urlOnSite = getOnSiteGridPageUrl(page, pageSize);
      var columns   = $scope.gridApi.grid.columns;
      var payloadOnSite   = getGridPagePayload(sortColumns, columns);
      sendOnSiteGridPageRequest(urlOnSite, payloadOnSite);
    };
```

#### Jade

```
tabset(ng-if="dataConstant.item.location_type !== 'On-Site Depot'")
    tab(heading="Audit Grid", select="tabShown = !tabShown", desselect="tabShown = !tabShown")
      div(ui-grid-auto-resize, id="grid1", ui-grid="gridOptions1", ui-grid-pagination, ui-grid-edit, ui-grid-row-edit, class="auditGrid")
    tab(heading="On Site Depot Parts", select="tabShown = !tabShown", desselect="tabShown = !tabShown")
      div(ui-grid-auto-resize, id="grid12", ui-grid="gridOptions12", ui-grid-pagination, ui-grid-edit, ui-grid-row-edit, class="auditGrid")
```

They are fired in the onRegisterApi for $scope.gridOptions1 and $scope.gridOptions12.

When calling the functions in $scope.gridOptions1 everything works as it should for `sortListener` but `sortOnSiteListener` fires as well.

I can't seem to figure out why this is bubbling.

Comment: Where are the tables HTML and the grid binding? It sounds like a binding problem.

Comment: updated with the jade for the grid

Comment: There's not enough info to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not pass the same filterfunction-reference into your different gridOptions.

If you got something like:

```
var genderFilter = { someFilter }; // mistake

var gridOptions1 = {
  data: ...,
  columnDefs: [
  { field: 'foo', filter: genderFilter },
  ...
};

var gridOptions12 = {
  data: ...,
  columnDefs: [
  { field: 'foo', filter: genderFilter },
  ...
};
```

Instead use a new function for every Grid.

```
var genderFilter1 = { someFilter };
var genderFilter2 = { someFilter };

var gridOptions1 = {
  data: ...,
  columnDefs: [
  { field: 'foo', filter: genderFilter1 },
  ...
};

var gridOptions12 = {
  data: ...,
  columnDefs: [
  { field: 'foo', filter: genderFilter2 },
  ...
};
```

You can use a cloning function or create a new instance by hand.

See [Plunkr with WRONG setup](http://plnkr.co/edit/luIbNH76FqV47m70RtnP?p=preview) and [Plunkr with RIGHT setup](http://plnkr.co/edit/r8utvULZM382iPWPOzCb?p=preview). The Gender-Column is the one to watch out for.